# Error when moving project from Windows to Linux "mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Public_Controller' not found"

Tags: php, codeigniter

After moving my project from Windows to Linux all I get is a blank page
When I look in the logs I get this error:

```
[Wed Oct 03 22:59:14 2012] [warn] [client MY.IP.] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Public_Controller' not found in /home/clients/client13/web32/web/application/modules/welcome/controllers/welcome.php on line 11
```

The server is running Fast-CGI (I've also tried Mod-PHP just in case)

Line 10 to 16 of the file:

```
class Welcome extends Public_Controller
{
function Welcome()
{
parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is case sensitive when it comes to file naming conventions. Double check the cases on your controllers. Specifically, make sure your file is called `Public_Controller.php`

Comment: Thanks. It was called Public_controller.php